# How to select first-n/top-n rows from a query's resultant if its count is more than a given number?

Tags: sql

I have a query that returns more than 1000 rows.

Step1:

```
with total_res as (
select table1.col1, table1.col2, table2.col3,... table2.coln 
from table1 join table2
    on table1.keycol=table2.keycol
where table1.col4='ABCD' and table2.col5 <= '02-02-2022'
   order by table1.col1 desc)
```

In my requirement, I have to return the first 350rows by ordering `col3` in `desc` if the output of the above query contain more than 1000rows.

So I added a row number column like below to add sequential numbers to the resulset from above.
Step2:

```
select col1, col2, col2...coln, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col3 desc) as number from total_res;
```

What I don't understand now is how can I check if the output from step2 contains more than 350 rows and if so, select the first 350 rows.
Could anyone let me know how can I achieve this ? Or is there a better way to do it than using row_number ?

Answer (score 0):

try like below in 2nd step check highest number>350 and then limit the value 350

```
with cte as
(
select col1, col2, col2...coln, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col3  as number from total_res

) select * from cte 
  where 350 < ( select max(number) from cte)
order by number
limit 350
```

Comment: Does `limit` here guarantee the first 350 ?